# What does 'We didn't bring you up to watch yourself cancer.' mean?

Tags: meaning

'bring up' is a kind of collocations?
I would like to know the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!   Please tell us the source of this sentence. Did you make it up? Did you read it somewhere? If so, what was the publication and the author. If you have a link to the text please provide it. Thank you.  (As Cascabel says, the sentence makes no sense in English)

Comment: Probably this: 
  “Do you think it's clever? Filling your lungs with rubbish, killing yourself? We didn't bring you up to watch you give yourself cancer! We don't need this, certainly not at this time, not when —”

  “Enough!” Dad shouts, and we both jump.    From a book called "Lord Loss"  https://tinyurl.com/1p6vubz1

Comment: That's right. Thank you.

Comment: If it is indeed the question that @Pete posted in the comment above, then you have mangled it and turned it from a grammatical English sentence into word salad, Sorata. The subject of _watch_ in the infinitive clause is "we", not "you", as you can see by the fact that the object is "you", not "yourself".

Answer (score 1):

I think the original was probably...

> We did not bring you up *to watch / have you die of* cancer

[***Bring up***](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bring-up)

is a "phrasal verb" which means "*to raise and educate*" a child.

No parent wants to accept the loss a child for any reason: it is not the natural order of things.

Comment: Thank you so much.